# Que podemos chamar a uma pessoa que fica de fora a ver os outros dançar?

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

Alguém conhece uma palavra ou expressão que designe uma pessoa que, num baile ou discoteca, fique tipicamente de fora a ver os outros dançar? Por não ter par ou por não estar interessado em dançar.

**Atualização**. Este foi o meu primeiríssimo post aqui no site, e eu ainda não sabia que neste tipo de perguntas é útil incluir uma ou duas frase exemplificando o uso da palavra ou expressão pedida. Ajuda a quem quiser responder a ver exatamente o que se pretende e a excluir o que não serve. Então vá vai.

> Preciso de um ___________ que me guarde o casaco enquanto eu vou dançar.
>
> Hoje não danças? Estás armada em ___________ ?

E **para o caso de servir de inspiração** a alguém, eu quis o termo para traduzir uma passagem do Kipling. O Kipling fictional tinha um amigo perdido de bêbedo num baile e precisava de alguém que tomasse conta dele. Então:

> Sentei [o amigo bêbedo] num canto sossegado do salão de jantar e fui procurar um ________ em quem pudesse confiar.

A palavra que ele usa é *wall-prop*, uma barra de madeira ou metal para segurar ([*prop*, Oxford Learner’s](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prop_1?q=prop)), neste caso uma parede, e impedir que ela caia. A [Kipling Society](http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/rg_friendsfriend_notes.htm) diz que neste caso é um “não-dançante que se encosta a uma parede”. Têm aqui a história completa: [“A Friend’s Friend”, *Plain Tales from the Hills*](http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/PlainTales/friendfriend.html).

Eu contento-me com uma expressão que seja compreendida como ’pessoa que se mantém fora da dança’, mas se quiserem algo que tenha que ver com paredes, estão à vontade.

Comment: É um "poste"? ;)

Comment: @JorgeB.,  _poste_ compreende-se em contexto favorável, por exemplo, _Vais com o João ao baile? Não esperes que ele dance; ele fica sempre armado em poste._ Mas compreender-se-ia, por exemplo, em, _Doem-te os pés para dançar? Então procura um poste para te fazer companhia_?

Comment: Acho que sim @Jacinto, mas não é muito usual.

Comment: The original term is "wall flower", not "wall prop". However, yes, a person who leans against a wall, can be propping it up. People just make up stuff in English all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Pode-se referir a um **pé-de-chumbo** quando acha que alguém não tem muito jeito para dançar. Tal pessoa, no seu parecer, possui pés tão pesados que fazem lembrar [chumbo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chumbo) e, se ainda não o comprovou numa dança anterior, existe uma grande probabilidade de tal acontecer.

Apesar de no [priberam, o seu significado ser apenas o de uma "Pessoa de andar lento e pesado"](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/p%C3%A9-de-chumbo), esta expressão foi utilizada para criar o nome de uma famosa organização de danças em Portugal: a [PédeXumbo](http://www.pedexumbo.com), a qual realiza eventos para o ensino da dança. Creio, por isso, que seja também uma expressão mais comum no português de Portugal.

O(A) pé-de-chumbo não tem necessariamente de "ficar de fora a ver os outros dançar", porém é aconselhável ou implícito que tal aconteça. Porém, se acha que é suficientemente corajoso para lhe dar uma lição, pode desafiá-lo(a) da seguinte forma:

> Vem cá que eu já te ensino a mexer esses pezinhos de chumbo.

Comment: Em certos contextos _pé-de-chumbo_ é capaz de funcionar. Por exemplo, _Encontrei um pé-de-chumbo para me guardar o casaco enquanto eu fui dançar_. É claro que pode haver maratonistas que por timidez ou desinteresse se armem em pés-de-chumbo num baile.

Comment: Armoot, ao fim de seis anos juntei mais informação à pergunta. Se te ocorrer alguma coisa e quiseres acrescentar à tua resposta, a comissão agradece.

Answer (score 5):

**"tomar um chá de cadeira"**, uma expressão já não muito usada nos dias de hoje, significa que a pessoa não conseguiu um par para dançar durante toda a festa.

ex. "como foi a festa?"
"Ah, tomei um chá de cadeira danado."

Segundo o Priberam

> - [**chá de cadeira**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ch%C3%A1-de-cadeira)
>   substantivo masculino
> - 1. [Brasil, Informal]  Espera longa.
> - 2. [Brasil, Informal]  **Falta de convite para dançar, num baile**.

> Plural: chás de cadeira.
> • **Grafia anterior ao Acordo Ortográfico** de 1990: chá-de-cadeira

Em inglês temos o termo **"a wallflower"** (a person who has no one to dance with or who feels shy, awkward, or excluded at a party.) mas desconheço qualquer substantivo com o mesmo significado em pt-BR.

Comment: Não conhecia a expressão. Mas de qualquer modo estou a pensar em alguém que fica de fora, possivelmente, por não querer dançar, não necessariamente por ninguém querer dançar com ela. Editei a pergunta para deixar isso claro.

Comment: Inclui exemplos de uso, e possível fonte de inspiração na pergunta. Se te ocorrer mais alguma coisa, tás à vontade. Vendo de novo a tua resposta, para chamar a uma pessoa, teria de ficar algo como *tomador de chá de cadeira*. Preferia uma coisa mais compacta...

Comment: Não tem de ser substantivo só, uma só palavra. Pode ser uma expressão qualquer que se possa chamar a alguém e pôr nos buracos dos meus exemplos.